# How to make a terminal like textarea, that you can type in?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I want to make a textarea where you can type inside of it, with a black background and green text and the ">_" blinks.
 How would i go about making this?

Comment: [How to create interactive terminal like website?](https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this in your CSS:

```
textarea {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #00ff00;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: courier new;
}
```

Comment: you want a vote up, and all you did was showed me abit of css that i already know? XD

Comment: this will satisfy only color requirement

Comment: My bad did not see you wanted a blink inside the textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo -TextArea</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryui.css">

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myTextArea").html(">_");

setInterval(function(){
removeAndAppendBlickWraper();
},2000);

});

function removeAndAppendBlickWraper(){
        removeAndAppendBlick(function(){

                var text = $("#myTextArea").val(),
                withCursortext =text+">_";
                $("#myTextArea").val(withCursortext);

        });
}
function removeAndAppendBlick(callback){
var text = $("#myTextArea").val();
 var witoutCursor = text.substr(0,text.lastIndexOf(">_"));
 $("#myTextArea").val(witoutCursor);
 setTimeout(function(){
 callback();
 },1500);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="myTextArea" style="background-color: black;color: green;" row="5"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amitkate41/kkpvzxct/) (thanks to amit kate)

Comment: It won't load :/ i've tried to add the jqueryui and jquery to the file, but its just a white blank page. Would help greatly if you could add them by default. thanks :)

Comment: do you have those file with you .If yes then check your files path.According to example ,add those files within same folder

Comment: k, it's working, and it was an error with your code, check your title tag xD.